# Laravel API returns file and client must show download dialog

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, download

I am developing an Laravel 5.3 API Bridge to download some files to various systems. What I want to achieve:

1. User clicks download button
2. PHP web does a cURL post request to API
3. API response may be a file or a 404 HTTP Code
4. Client browser shows file download dialog

API method:

```
    $reportService = new ReportService($request->get('vRefGMS'));
    $reportData = $reportService->handle();
    if ($reportData) {
        $serverService = new NetServerService($reportData);
        $csvFile = $serverService->handle();
        if ($csvFile != null) {
            return response()->file($csvFile);
        } else {
            return abort(404);
        }
    } else {
        return abort(404);
    }
```

Now I will show you the code I had try.

PHP code in the web for the download:

```
    $uri = $this->getEndpointShow($this->reportCode, SELF::ENDPOINT_REPORT_DOWNLOAD);
    $file = $this->apiConnection->downloadReport($uri, $this->reportCode);
    if ($file) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        flush();
        readfile($file);
    } else {
        echo "alert('Can´t find a report file')";
    }
```

And the downloadReport method:

```
public function downloadReport($uri, $reportCode)
{
    if (!$reportCode) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("No report Code");
    }
    $cURLConnection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, self::BASE_API_URL . $uri);
    curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "vRefGMS=$reportCode");
    curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . self::API_ACCESS_TOKEN
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($cURLConnection);

    if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($cURLConnection), curl_errno($cURLConnection));
    }

    curl_close($cURLConnection);

    return $response;
}
```

As you can see in the PHP code for the download I have a `$file` var which always comes blank `$file = ''`. I did also try on the api with `return response()->download($csvFile)` with the same result.

Is possible that I am missunderstanding concepts, but I cannot achieve the file download. How can get this file?

**EDIT:**

The api is returning a file, because if I go on the cli to make a cURL request to the API that's the response:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/test


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : 1;!;1;1;
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Accept-Ranges: bytes
                    Content-Length: 8
                    Cache-Control: public
                    Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2020 01:59:37 GMT
                    Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Feb 2020 12:11:04 GMT
                    Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImdFb...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Accept-Ranges, bytes], [Content-Length, 8], [Cache-Control, public], [Date, Mon, 24 Feb 2020
                    01:59:37 GMT]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 8
```

So what I am doing wrong in the web code which shows me blank file?

Comment: So what is your actual question now? This appears to be several problems crammed into one. Does your API return the correct thing to begin with, if you call it from somewhere else? _“Is possible that I am missunderstanding concepts”_ - that probably as well, yes. If your API call was supposed to return the actual file _content_ (?) - then using `basename`, `filesize` and `readfile` on that value would of course not make sense. All of these functions take a file system path as parameter.

Comment: My API returns the file (if I call from a browser the URL it tries to download the file). But in the web code $file var is blank `$file = ''`, just before calling basename, filesize or readfile, so each code of line is not executed, just the `alert()`

Comment: If you call it in your browser, you are presumably talking about a GET request. In your cURL code, you tried to make a POST request.

Comment: Of course, I just copypasted the code on a Get endpoint to test it in a browser. Same code, with harcoded parameters.

Comment: Your CLI cURL request is also just a GET request.